# failed to access subdomain from main domain: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: go, cors, go-gin

## versions

```
go 1.17
github.com/gin-contrib/cors v1.3.1
github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.7.7
```

## problem

I run gin REST API server in my subdomain.
React app placed in main domain access to the API server with GET method and POST method, but get cors policy error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<subdomain>.<domain>.xxx/api/v1/users' from origin 'https://<domain>.xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

On web search, I found the same issue and some solutions, but they didn't work in my case.

## Code

All of these programs got the same error.

### Case 1

```golang
package gateway

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func RunServer() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.Default())
    api := r.Group("/api")
    v1 := api.Group("/v1")
    userRouters(v1)
    err := r.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to run gateway: %v", err)
    }
}
```

### Case 2

```golang
package gateway

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func RunServer() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Content-Type"},
        AllowCredentials: false,
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
    }))
    api := r.Group("/api")
    v1 := api.Group("/v1")
    userRouters(v1)
    err := r.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to run gateway: %v", err)
    }
}
```

### Case 3

[Missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response header. · Issue #29 · gin-contrib/cors](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/issues/29#issuecomment-397859488)

```golang
package gateway

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func CORS() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

func RunServer() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(CORS())
    api := r.Group("/api")
    v1 := api.Group("/v1")
    userRouters(v1)
    err := r.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to run gateway: %v", err)
    }
}
```

## preflight from terminal

```
> curl 'https://alb.skhole.club/api/v1/authz' \
  -X 'OPTIONS' \
  -H 'authority: alb.skhole.club' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  -H 'access-control-request-headers: content-type' \
  -H 'access-control-request-method: POST' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'origin: https://skhole.club' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'referer: https://skhole.club/' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-site' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed -i
HTTP/2 502 
server: awselb/2.0
date: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 04:04:13 GMT
content-type: text/html
content-length: 524

<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

## Solved

This is caused by the `aws_lb_target_group` settings.
I set the protocol HTTPS in the target group even though I gave ACM certificates to only Route 53 and ALB.
I replaced HTTPS with HTTP, and now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good first step to diagnose such kind of problem is to check the preflight request in the Chrome DevTools directly.

[image: Chrome DevTools screenshot]

**Notes**:

1. Check `Disable cache` in case that the preflight response is cached.
2. Find the request whose type is `preflight`.

The next step is to copy the preflight request as `curl` command (right click on the request, select `Copy`->`Copy as cURL` in the context menu) and test the request with the `curl` tool directly (remember to modify the command to add the `-i` option to print the response headers).

It seems that you encountered the issue on a production environment, it's possible that a reverse proxy sitting between the browser and your service blocks the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header by default. Try to send the preflight request directly to your service and see if there is anything different.

**Update** (after the preflight response is provided):

It turns out that this is not a CORS issue at all. The request failed with the status code `502 Bad Gateway`. The application is not deployed correctly.

---

BTW, I have tested Case 1 and it works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http/httputil"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.Use(cors.Default())
    api := r.Group("/api")
    v1 := api.Group("/v1")
    v1.POST("users", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        buf, err := httputil.DumpRequest(ctx.Request, true)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("failed to dump request: %v", err)
            return
        }

        log.Printf("%s", buf)
    })
    err := r.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to run gateway: %v", err)
    }
    r.Run()
}
```

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users' \
  -X 'OPTIONS' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6' \
  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type' \
  -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5501' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:5501/' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --compressed -i
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Length,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 43200
Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 03:50:06 GMT
```

Comment: I ran the preflight access from the terminal copied from the Chrome dev tools Network tab. It failed too. In localhost, there is no problem as you tried but it's failing in production in AWS. I'll try the simplest code you wrote to isolate the cause.

Comment: It is very likely there is something sitting between the browser and the service blocks the header.  Can you share the response?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. I added the preflight response. Do you want any else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. `502 Bad Gateway` means that the request does not even reach your service. Check the configuration of the load balancer, there should be something wrong.

Comment: A simple get request (`curl -i 'https://alb.skhole.club/api/v1/authz'`) results in `502 Bad Gateway` after ~2 minutes. Obviously, the load balancer is not configured correctly. Try to send a request to your service on the same server to make sure the service is on first.

Comment: You mean this is my networking problem, not cors problem, right? I hadn't found out that if you didn't help. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're right, it's not a CORS problem because the request fails before it's handled by the CORS code. But I would call it a configuration issue instead of a network issue.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's just poor wording. I check my AWS architecture defined as terraform files. I took your time a lot. I appreciate you.

Comment: You're welcome! It's my pleasure.