# Do we have any solutions for the Gin CORS issue with non-simple requests (POST JSON)?

Tags: javascript, go, cors, go-gin

### Problem Description

I have tried several solutions, but none of them worked. Here are the details:

I have a website configured at localhost:8080, and I want this web app to access the Gin server at localhost:9999 using Axios.

Here are the solutions I have tried:

```
func main() {
    r.Use(cors.Default())
    //r.Use(Cors())
    //r.Use(Cors1())
    r.Use(Cors3())
    r.POST("/inlog", func(c *gin.Context) {
        print(c)
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{"status": "OK", "message": "pong",})
    })

    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run(":9999")
}

func Cors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowAllOrigins:  true,
        AllowMethods:     []string{"POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"*"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length", "Authorization", "Content-Type"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge:           12 * time.Hour,
    },
    )
}

func Cors1() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        method := c.Request.Method
        origin := c.Request.Header.Get("Origin")
        if origin != "" {
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, UPDATE")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,AccessToken,X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Cache-Control,Content-Language,Content-Type,Expires,Last-Modified,Pragma,FooBar")
        }
        if method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS")
            c.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}

func Cors3() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(context *gin.Context) {
        method := context.Request.Method
        context.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        context.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,AccessToken,X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, Token, x-token")
        context.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH, PUT")
        context.Header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Length, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type")
        context.Header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")

        if method == "OPTIONS" {
            context.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
        }
        context.Next()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, these three solutions cannot solve my problem. They only allow my website to access the server using the GET method, while POST requests always result in an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/inlog/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `return` instead of `c.AbortWithStatus`.

Comment: Haven't used gin, but with the default http.Mux `"/inlog/" != "/inlog"`. Try removing the trailing slash in the frontend, or add one in the server.

Comment: Try @Peter's suggestion first. This looks like the issue. If it still does not work, check the requests log in DevTools and share them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75935458/1369400 for how to diagnose such kind of problem.

Comment: What does the client code look like? Edit your question and add the code responsible for sending the problematic request.

Comment: `Cors` likely fails because Gin's CORS middleware is designed to ignore the wildcard exception for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. `Cors1` is incorrect (not enough room in a comment to explain why). `Cors3` is incompatible with credentialed requests. Don't try to re-implement CORS by manually setting headers, esp. if you're not intimately familiar with the protocol. Instead, rely on some well-designed library. I'm biased, but I recommend [jub0bs/fcors](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/fcors); it's [compatible with Gin](https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors-examples/blob/main/gin/main.go).

Answer (score 1):

You did not show us your request and how it was made. But once I had problems with that too and the problem was the slash in the request.

Note that your route do not have the slash at end.

```
    r.POST("/inlog", func(c *gin.Context) {
       //Rest of your code
    }
```

If your client is calling it with a slash at end, it might turn in error for you together with a 301 error message.

So make sure you are calling
*http://127.0.0.1:9999/inlog* and **NOT** *http://127.0.0.1:9999/inlog/*

Comment: lol, for me it was the other way around. I have to put "/" at the end of the url to fix the problem. Probably because of the differences in how I group my endpoints compared to yours. Still, thanks!